# Memory managment. Dealloc. iOS

Tags: ios, ios4, memory-management, dealloc

Is this correct?

```
- (void)dealloc {

    [super dealloc];

    [stageObjects release];
}
```

Or should I call

```
[super dealloc]
```

Always after all releases, I mean last line of this function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must always call `[super dealloc];` last. After all, this very object might always be deallocated after the call to super returns.

Answer (score 1):

```
[super dealloc];
```

should be the last line to call in dealloc method.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make macro as below for dealloc objects and because of it you should not write method every time.

RELEASE_SAFELY (object) [object release], object=nil